# Website not working due to htaccess

Tags: htaccess, web-development, mod-rewrite, http-code-500

My website was fine (apologies in advance for not being a webmaster or developer) until SSL was enforced through hosting platform - a 500 error code/page showing `internal server error`. Spoke to hosting company, who basically said I need to check my htaccess file, as they `Issue with the codes in the htaccess`. I have checked by removing the  codes then website starts loading the `Page Cant be found error`.

I ran the htaccess info through lynx.com, and these are the issues - not sure what it wants me to do:

Lyxx found 11 problems in the code segment(s) below.

```
line 67:        # DEFLATE by extension
line 68:    (1)     AddOutputFilter DEFLATE js css htm html xml
line 69:        </IfModule>
line 89:        RewriteEngine On
line 90:    (1)     RewriteBase
line 91:    (20)    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
line 92:        RewriteRule .* - [E=W3TC_SSL:_ssl]
line 93:    (20)    RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} =443
line 94:        RewriteRule .* - [E=W3TC_SSL:_ssl]
line 95:    (20)    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Encoding} gzip
line 96:        RewriteRule .* - [E=W3TC_ENC:_gzip]
line 97:    (20)    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !=POST
line 98:        RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} =""
line 99:    (49)    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \/$
line 100:   (20)    RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !(comment_author|wp\postpass|w3tc_logged_out|wordpress_logged_in) [NC]
line 101:   (1)     RewriteCond "%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/wp-content/cache/page_enhanced/{HTTP_HOST}/%{REQUEST_URI}/_index%{ENV:W3TC_SSL}.html%{ENV:W3TC_ENC}" -F
line 102:       RewriteRule .* "/wp-content/cache/page_enhanced/%{HTTP_HOST}/%{REQUEST_URI}/_index%{ENV:W3TC_SSL}.html%{ENV:W3TC_ENC}" [L]
line 172:       # DEFLATE by extension
line 173:   (1)     AddOutputFilter DEFLATE js css htm html xml
line 174:       </IfModule>
line 213:       RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?thenowherekids.com$
line 214:   (20)    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
line 215:       RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

Prior to this issue, I had deactivated all plugins except for Elementor and Elementor Pro - and then downloaded a copy of website to desktop (to backup).

Any help would be greatly appreciated - thank you

Full htaccess below

```
AddType application/font-woff .woff
AddType application/font-woff2 .woff2
AddType application/java .class
AddType application/javascript .js2
AddType application/json .json
AddType application/msword .doc .docx
AddType application/pdf .pdf
AddType application/vnd.ms-access .mdb
AddType application/vnd.ms-excel .xla .xls .xlsx .xlt .xlw
AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject .eot
AddType application/vnd.ms-opentype ._otf ._ttf
AddType application/vnd.ms-powerpoint .pot .pps .ppt .pptx
AddType application/vnd.ms-project .mpp
AddType application/vnd.ms-write .wri
AddType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.chart .odc
AddType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.database .odb
AddType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.formula .odf
AddType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.graphics .odg
AddType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.presentation .odp
AddType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet .ods
AddType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text .odt
AddType application/x-font-otf .otf
AddType application/x-font-ttf .ttf .ttc
AddType application/x-gzip .gz .gzip
AddType application/x-javascript .js
AddType application/x-msdownload .exe
AddType application/x-shockwave-flash .swf
AddType application/x-tar .tar
AddType application/zip .zip
AddType audio/midi .mid .midi
AddType audio/mpeg .mp3 .m4a
AddType audio/ogg .ogg
AddType audio/wav .wav
AddType audio/wma .wma
AddType audio/x-realaudio .ra .ram
AddType image/avif .avif
AddType image/avif-sequence .avifs
AddType image/bmp .bmp
AddType image/gif .gif
AddType image/jpeg .jpg .jpeg .jpe
AddType image/png .png
AddType image/svg+xml .svg .svgz
AddType image/tiff .tif .tiff
AddType image/webp .webp
AddType image/x-icon .ico
AddType text/css .css
AddType text/javascript .js3
AddType text/x-component .htc
AddType text/x-js .js4
AddType video/asf .asf .asx .wax .wmv .wmx
AddType video/avi .avi
AddType video/divx .divx
AddType video/mp4 .mp4 .m4v
AddType video/mpeg .mpeg .mpg .mpe
AddType video/ogg .ogv
AddType video/quicktime .mov .qt
AddType video/webm .webm


# BEGIN W3TC Browser Cache
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary
  </IfModule>
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css text/x-component application/x-javascript application/javascript text/javascript text/x-js text/html text/richtext image/svg+xml text/plain text/xsd text/xsl text/xml image/x-icon application/json
  <IfModule mod_mime.c>
    # DEFLATE by extension
    AddOutputFilter DEFLATE js css htm html xml
  </IfModule>
</IfModule>
<FilesMatch "\.(css|htc|js|js2|js3|js4|CSS|HTC|JS|JS2|JS3|JS4)$">
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
         Header set X-Powered-By "W3 Total Cache/0.9.3"
    </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "\.(html|htm|rtf|rtx|svg|svgz|txt|xsd|xsl|xml|HTML|HTM|RTF|RTX|SVG|SVGZ|TXT|XSD|XSL|XML)$">
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
         Header set X-Powered-By "W3 Total Cache/0.9.3"
    </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "\.(asf|asx|wax|wmv|wmx|avi|bmp|class|divx|doc|docx|eot|exe|gif|gz|gzip|ico|jpg|jpeg|jpe|json|mdb|mid|midi|mov|qt|mp3|m4a|mp4|m4v|mpeg|mpg|mpe|mpp|otf|odb|odc|odf|odg|odp|ods|odt|ogg|pdf|png|pot|pps|ppt|pptx|ra|ram|svg|svgz|swf|tar|tif|tiff|ttf|ttc|wav|wma|wri|xla|xls|xlsx|xlt|xlw|zip|ASF|ASX|WAX|WMV|WMX|AVI|BMP|CLASS|DIVX|DOC|DOCX|EOT|EXE|GIF|GZ|GZIP|ICO|JPG|JPEG|JPE|JSON|MDB|MID|MIDI|MOV|QT|MP3|M4A|MP4|M4V|MPEG|MPG|MPE|MPP|OTF|ODB|ODC|ODF|ODG|ODP|ODS|ODT|OGG|PDF|PNG|POT|PPS|PPT|PPTX|RA|RAM|SVG|SVGZ|SWF|TAR|TIF|TIFF|TTF|TTC|WAV|WMA|WRI|XLA|XLS|XLSX|XLT|XLW|ZIP)$">
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
         Header set X-Powered-By "W3 Total Cache/0.9.3"
    </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
# END W3TC Browser Cache
# BEGIN W3TC Page Cache core
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
    RewriteRule .* - [E=W3TC_SSL:_ssl]
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} =443
    RewriteRule .* - [E=W3TC_SSL:_ssl]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Encoding} gzip
    RewriteRule .* - [E=W3TC_ENC:_gzip]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !=POST
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} =""
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \/$
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !(comment_author|wp\-postpass|w3tc_logged_out|wordpress_logged_in) [NC]
    RewriteCond "%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/wp-content/cache/page_enhanced/%{HTTP_HOST}/%{REQUEST_URI}/_index%{ENV:W3TC_SSL}.html%{ENV:W3TC_ENC}" -F
    RewriteRule .* "/wp-content/cache/page_enhanced/%{HTTP_HOST}/%{REQUEST_URI}/_index%{ENV:W3TC_SSL}.html%{ENV:W3TC_ENC}" [L]
</IfModule>
# END W3TC Page Cache core
# BEGIN W3TC Browser Cache
<IfModule mod_mime.c>
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresByType text/css A31536000
    ExpiresByType text/x-component A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/x-javascript A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/javascript A31536000
    ExpiresByType text/javascript A31536000
    ExpiresByType text/x-js A31536000
    ExpiresByType video/asf A31536000
    ExpiresByType video/avi A31536000
    ExpiresByType image/avif A31536000
    ExpiresByType image/avif-sequence A31536000
    ExpiresByType image/bmp A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/java A31536000
    ExpiresByType video/divx A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/msword A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/x-msdownload A31536000
    ExpiresByType image/gif A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/x-gzip A31536000
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon A31536000
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg A31536000
    ExpiresByType image/webp A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/json A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-access A31536000
    ExpiresByType audio/midi A31536000
    ExpiresByType video/quicktime A31536000
    ExpiresByType audio/mpeg A31536000
    ExpiresByType video/mp4 A31536000
    ExpiresByType video/mpeg A31536000
    ExpiresByType video/webm A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-project A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/x-font-otf A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-opentype A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.database A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.chart A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.formula A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.graphics A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.presentation A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text A31536000
    ExpiresByType audio/ogg A31536000
    ExpiresByType video/ogg A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/pdf A31536000
    ExpiresByType image/png A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-powerpoint A31536000
    ExpiresByType audio/x-realaudio A31536000
    ExpiresByType image/svg+xml A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/x-tar A31536000
    ExpiresByType image/tiff A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/x-font-ttf A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-opentype A31536000
    ExpiresByType audio/wav A31536000
    ExpiresByType audio/wma A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-write A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/font-woff A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/font-woff2 A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-excel A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/zip A31536000
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css text/x-component application/x-javascript application/javascript text/javascript text/x-js text/html text/richtext text/plain text/xsd text/xsl text/xml image/bmp application/java application/msword application/vnd.ms-fontobject application/x-msdownload image/x-icon application/json application/vnd.ms-access video/webm application/vnd.ms-project application/x-font-otf application/vnd.ms-opentype application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.database application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.chart application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.formula application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.graphics application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.presentation application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text audio/ogg application/pdf application/vnd.ms-powerpoint image/svg+xml application/x-shockwave-flash image/tiff application/x-font-ttf application/vnd.ms-opentype audio/wav application/vnd.ms-write application/font-woff application/font-woff2 application/vnd.ms-excel
    <IfModule mod_mime.c>
        # DEFLATE by extension
        AddOutputFilter DEFLATE js css htm html xml
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
<FilesMatch "\.(css|htc|less|js|js2|js3|js4|CSS|HTC|LESS|JS|JS2|JS3|JS4)$">
    FileETag MTime Size
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header unset Set-Cookie
    </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "\.(html|htm|rtf|rtx|txt|xsd|xsl|xml|HTML|HTM|RTF|RTX|TXT|XSD|XSL|XML)$">
    FileETag MTime Size
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "\.(asf|asx|wax|wmv|wmx|avi|avif|avifs|bmp|class|divx|doc|docx|eot|exe|gif|gz|gzip|ico|jpg|jpeg|jpe|webp|json|mdb|mid|midi|mov|qt|mp3|m4a|mp4|m4v|mpeg|mpg|mpe|webm|mpp|otf|_otf|odb|odc|odf|odg|odp|ods|odt|ogg|ogv|pdf|png|pot|pps|ppt|pptx|ra|ram|svg|svgz|swf|tar|tif|tiff|ttf|ttc|_ttf|wav|wma|wri|woff|woff2|xla|xls|xlsx|xlt|xlw|zip|ASF|ASX|WAX|WMV|WMX|AVI|AVIF|AVIFS|BMP|CLASS|DIVX|DOC|DOCX|EOT|EXE|GIF|GZ|GZIP|ICO|JPG|JPEG|JPE|WEBP|JSON|MDB|MID|MIDI|MOV|QT|MP3|M4A|MP4|M4V|MPEG|MPG|MPE|WEBM|MPP|OTF|_OTF|ODB|ODC|ODF|ODG|ODP|ODS|ODT|OGG|OGV|PDF|PNG|POT|PPS|PPT|PPTX|RA|RAM|SVG|SVGZ|SWF|TAR|TIF|TIFF|TTF|TTC|_TTF|WAV|WMA|WRI|WOFF|WOFF2|XLA|XLS|XLSX|XLT|XLW|ZIP)$">
    FileETag MTime Size
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header unset Set-Cookie
    </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Referrer-Policy "no-referrer-when-downgrade"
</IfModule>
# END W3TC Browser Cache
# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress

# Begin EnforceSSL example.com
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
</IfModule>
# End EnforceSSL
```

**UPDATE 8-Dec-2022**

I have moved the below to the top of the page:

```
# Begin EnforceSSL example.com
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
</IfModule>
# End EnforceSSL
```

I also deleted line 90

However, on closer inspection there are only two parts on the `.htaccess` file on the server, and the enforce SSL keeps moving to the bottom, after the `# BEGIN WORDPRESS`

When I refresh my site, it gives me the following:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '*', expecting end of file in /hermes/bosnacweb04/bosnacweb04/bosnacweb04at/b371/dot.example/public_html/wp-config.php on line 85

Please advise.

Comment: I think you may need to post ypur htaccess here. But, please replace your domain with example.com

Comment: Hi - Added, but the styling is terrible - any tips would be great - thanks

Comment: I had formatted it earlier. Before it wad approved, you edited it and it got last. I have formatted it again. Please wait for the changes to be reviewed by others.  Everything is peer reviewed.

Comment: Thank you @RohitGupta

Answer (score 2):

You need to check the web server's (Apache) error log for the details of this error. A "500 Internal Server Error" response is just a generic response that *something* serious occurred and the server was unable to continue.

Having said that, the 500 error is likely caused by the `RewriteBase` directive in the following code block (line#90):

> ```
> # BEGIN W3TC Page Cache core
> <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
>     RewriteEngine On
>     RewriteBase
>     RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
>     RewriteRule .* - [E=W3TC_SSL:_ssl]
> ```

In the above, the `RewriteBase` directive is missing an argument (the URL-path). It should (probably) read `RewriteBase /` (the lone slash indicating the root directory).

However, the `RewriteBase` directive is out of place in this particular code block and should probably be removed altogether. It's not being used by any of the directives in that code block (ie. between the `# BEGIN W3TC Page Cache core` and `# END W3TC Page Cache core` comment markers). If it is implemented here then it's only going to be overridden by the `RewriteBase` directive that occurs later in the file (in the `# BEGIN WordPress` section) - so it won't do anything anyway.

HOWEVER, the fact that these directives are enclosed between `# BEGIN W3TC Page Cache core` and `# END W3TC Page Cache core` comment markers implies it is maintained by a plugin. If that's the case then manually editing this code block might be futile since your changes might simply get overwritten by the plugin. (But you say you've "deactivated all plugins" from WordPress? Then why are these directives still here?)

> My website was fine ... until SSL was enforced through hosting platform

But the above `RewriteBase` directive has nothing to do with "enforcing SSL through the hosting platform"? These two issues would seem to be unrelated?

Is it possible this directive was manually edited by someone by mistake?

Another oddity is that you have two different code blocks enclosed in `# BEGIN W3TC Browser Cache` .. `# END W3TC Browser Cache` comment markers. This looks like it's been manually edited as it doesn't seem possible that a plugin would be able to manage both sections.

> ```
> # Begin EnforceSSL example.com
> <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
> RewriteEngine On
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$
> RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
> </IfModule>
> # End EnforceSSL
> ```

Finally, your code block that "enforces SSL" is in the wrong place (and incorrect) so is not doing what it's supposed to do. It is currently at the very end of the file so will only redirect requests for static files (and directories, which includes the homepage), not other WordPress URLs.

This code block needs to be at the very top of the `.htaccess` file.

And this should be a 301 (permanent) redirect, not a 302 (temporary) redirect (which is *implied*). But only change this to a 301 when you are sure it's working as intended since 301s are cached persistently by the browser so can make testing problematic. ie. change the `RewriteRule` flags from `[L]` to `[R=301,L]`.

However, the fact that this code block is again enclosed in comment markers makes me think it is maintained by a plugin?! Or was this just added by the "hosting platform" as you suggest?

This code block can also be simplified to just two lines:

```
# Force HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

The `<IfModule>` wrapper, `RewriteEngine` directive, additional *condition* and comment markers are all unnecessary.

---

#### Summary

As detailed above...

1. Remove the `RewriteBase` directive on line#90
2. Move the "HTTP to HTTPS" redirect from the bottom of the file to the top. And simplify as stated.

---

**UPDATE:** *Aside:*

> Lyxx found 11 problems in the code segment(s) below.

That Lyxx validator is *nonsense*!? It appears to have correctly identified the `RewriteBase` line (as I mentioned above), however, it just gives what looks like a meaningless error "code" and no explanation?! And all the other "problems" that have been highlighted are not "problems" at all!?

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to come back to me - nothing here was made or edited by me, so it is either the hosting site or a plugin. I had an issue with elementor, so i deactivated all plugins EXCEPT for the two needed (and the theme). I didnt move anything around - is it possible the host did it, and didnt know what they were doing? I dont know enough to know what is the next step - what do you recommend? Can i ensure all plugins are deactivated without accessing WP dashboard?

Comment: Tried to get the error log, but noticed that wp_content folder is missing - yet it was there yesterday as i made a backup...the rabbit hole gets deeper

Comment: @TheNowhereKids "is it possible the host did it, and didnt know what they were doing?" - It's very probable they don't know what they are doing, but it's very unlikely they would make any significant changes (except for perhaps commenting out a problematic directive). I've added a brief "summary" to my answer - these are the only changes that should be made, based on your question.

Comment: @TheNowhereKids "Tried to get the error log, but noticed that wp_content folder is missing" - The error log is not stored in your public HTML space - if you don't have full access to your server (do you?) then you should be able to access this via your hosting control panel if you don't know the location on the filesystem. Regarding the `wp_content` folder being missing - these things don't delete themselves and "plugins" should not have sufficient access rights on the filesystem to make changes like that.

Comment: @TheNowhereKids "Can i ensure all plugins are deactivated without accessing WP dashboard?" - If your have a WP specific question then that is probably better asked on the WordPress stack at https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @TheNowhereKids I've updated my answer with a note about the "Lyxx validator" as the output from that tool would seem to be rather meaningless! The additional "problems" that the tool highlights are not problems at all!

Comment: Thanks for the extra help @mrwhite. I made the two changes on the update you provided. The file on the site has two elements, not like the above - i have added an update

Comment: fixed - deleted Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '*', expecting end of file in /hermes/bosnacweb04/bosnacweb04/bosnacweb04at/b371/dot.example/public_html/wp-config.php on line 85